# How to determine value of ∫c f(z) dz given the following conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

c is the square going from I to 2-i and 2+i to -i.

$$f(z)=\frac{z^2-iz}{z+1}$$.

Here is what I thought,
finding the zeros and then finding the reside and finally integrating it?
it has one pole of order 1

residue at $z_0=-1$ is 1+i

$$\int 1+i\,dx$$ ( its integral of 1+i from i to 2-i)

- I am sorry i dont know how to wrok with stack.
  $$\int ​1+i \,dx$$
  *( its integral of 1+i from i to 2-i)

I don't know if I am right or wrong. Any help is appreciated

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I think you're just missing the last step of the residue theorem, you don't integrate the residues.

Comment: @Stephen Donovan and what the points i to 2-i and -i to 2+i for?

Comment: It's there to give you the domain of integration, which is actually more important than it may seem because we only want to count poles enclosed by the domain of integration. So here the function is analytic over the square so the integral is $0.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan I kinda get what you mean though still unclear how does that affect the final answer. could you please give me some more explanation on what happens?

Comment: Essentially, only poles enclosed by the contour matter, because the idea is that we can split the contour up into different contours so that each one has one pole and then the answers are given by Cauchy's integral theorem. For poles exterior to the contour, they never appear in any of those smaller contours so they never appear in the sum. Does that make sense?

Comment: @StephenDonovan yeah that makes sense. How did you come to conclusion that the square is analytic? and is that a rule that when ever its analytic the integral is zero?

Comment: So first off, just to clear this up it's not the square itself which is analytic, it's the function which is analytic over the region of the square. And we can come to this conclusion because by the quotient rule, the quotient of two functions is differentiable wherever both functions are differentiable and the denominator is not zero. The numerator and denominator are polynomials so they are differentiable everywhere, so the quotient is differentiable wherever $z + 1 \neq 0 \to z \neq -1.$

Comment: And yes, when you're integrating on a closed contour, if the integrand is differentiable over the entire region enclosed by the contour, the integral is $0$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Ok thanks let me think a bit on that

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f(z) = g(z)+ \frac{1+i}{z+1}$$ where $g(z) = z - (1+i)$. Denote by $\gamma$ the square on which we integrate. As $g$ is holomorphic
$$\oint_\gamma f(z) \ dz = \oint_\gamma \frac{1+i}{z+1} \ dz$$ and according to the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

$$\oint_\gamma f(z) \ dz = 2i\pi \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1+i}{z+1}, 1\right)$$

You can conclude with the formula

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1+i}{z+1}\right) = \lim\limits_{z \to -1} (z+1)\frac{1+i}{z+1} = 1+i$$

Comment: So I was right. Though i don't need to integrate? is that all I need to do?

Comment: and what the points i to 2-i and -i to 2+i  for?

Comment: I've just realized something, the pole isn't enclosed by the domain, $-1$ isn't in the square. So the integral should be $0.$